# image an upload fire storage, when the file is upload success but get download url is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a function where I am going to upload image from emulator which sends to firebase storage. I want to get the downloadURL and to be placed into firebase firestore but, I am not retrieving the download URL. Would appreciate help.. thank you! I am currently doing my project with firebase storage and firestore.

```js
var filePath = `${this.currentUser.uid}/${this.selectedBgImage.name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
      const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
      this.storage.upload(filePath, this.selectedBgImage).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
            
           console.log(url);
          });
        })
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
downloadURL: Observable<string>; 
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe()
```

> refer https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage